# The canonical form of the equation $y^3u_{xx}-4u_{yy}+\frac{6}{y}u_{y}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In each region where the type of the equation is conserved, reduce it to the canonical form
$$y^3u_{xx}-4u_{yy}+\frac{6}{y}u_{y}=0$$

I tried replacing the variables $\xi =x$ and $\eta =y^2$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=\frac{\partial }{\partial \xi },\frac{\partial }{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \eta }{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta }=2y\frac{\partial }{\partial \eta }$$
$$u_{xx}=u_{\xi \xi },u_{yy}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left ( 2y\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta } \right )=4\eta \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \eta ^2}=4y^2u_{\eta }$$

Then the equation is
$$y^3u_{\xi \xi }-16y^2u_{\eta \eta }+12yu_{\eta }=0$$

*Is this the canonical form of the equation? What to do next?*

Comment: Real analysis, calculus, ode!

Comment: Did I put the tags wrong?

Comment: @Dmitry This is a partial differential equation.

Comment: @Alex Jones thanks so much for the tip! Didn't see that tag in the search engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical forms for a second-order linear PDE fix the second-order terms into one of a handful of possible presentations. For the two-dimensional case, they are as follows:

1. Hyperbolic: $u_{xy} = H$ or $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = H$
2. Parabolic: $u_{xx} = H$ or $u_{yy} = H$
3. Elliptic: $u_{xx} - u_{yy} = H$

where each $H$ is a (possibly different) function of the lower-order terms. For equations not already in the canonical form, we can put them into the canonical form by a change a variables based on the second-order coefficients. Since these coefficients may vary with respect to the independent variables, the canonical form may also vary.

---

First, we have to determine the regions where type is conserved. To do this, we write our equation as

$$ Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} = H $$

where $A,B,C$ are functions of both $x$ and $y$, and $H$ is a function which subsumes the rest of the equation. Here,

$$ \begin{align*} A &= y^3 \\ B &= 0 \\ C &= -4 \\ H &= -\frac{6}{y}u_y \end{align*} $$

Next, we consider the sign of

$$\Delta = B^2 - 4AC = 16y^3$$

We can easily see that

1. $\Delta > 0$ when $y > 0$ ,
2. $\Delta = 0$ when $y = 0$, and
3. $\Delta < 0$ when $y < 0$,

which define the regions where the equation is hyperbolic, parabolic, and elliptic, respectively. Important to note that $y=0$ is excluded from the domain of definition of this equation (because of the $6/y$ term), so we only need to cover cases 1 and 3.

Now, we solve the pair of ODEs

$$ \frac{\text dy}{\text dx} = \frac{B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}  = \pm 2y^{-3/2}$$

to get solutions

$$ \phi_{1,2}(x,y) = \pm \frac{2}{5} y^{5/2} - 2x = c_{1,2} $$

If $y > 0$, we can go ahead and make the transformation

$$ \xi = \frac{2}{5} y^{5/2} - 2x  \\ \eta = - \frac{2}{5} y^{5/2} - 2x  $$

If $y < 0$, $\phi_{1,2}$ are complex, so instead we make the transformation to the real and imaginary parts

$$ \alpha = -2x \\ \beta = \frac{2}{5}(-y)^{5/2} $$

All that's left is to do the transformations defined by these systems. It's clear at this point that your error was in choosing the transformations, so I'll stop here and let you finish it out. You can use the expected forms above as a sanity check; if your result has the right second-order terms, you probably did it right.

Comment: An excellent answer and explanation!